# OCR tesseract Improve results on detailed background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I've been trying to utilize PyTesseract for OCR of book cover titles.
Results have been varying but ok. Yet i'm struggling with text which has pictures underneath.
I've tried a variety of (combinations of) methods:

- grayscale
- Noise removal
- Thresholding
- eroding
- canny

Yet for the images below, the best results I have gotten were [namuroi, sculpt, 1400] for the first image and [out] for the second. Those results were gotten with the *code below*, using dilation dominantly in the y-direction. Any tips on getting better results? The code is meant to be used on thousands of images, so can not be manually altered for each image. I'm willing to switch OCR libraries.

I had also been thinking about using a code to cut out the text parts, but manually cropping the images did not yield better results.

```
import cv2 
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

def deshadowVert(img):
    rgb_planes = cv2.split(img)

    result_planes = []
    result_norm_planes = []
    for plane in rgb_planes:
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (1,
                                                        5))  # to manipulate the orientation of dilution , large x means horizonatally dilating  more, large y means vertically dilating more

        dilated_img = cv2.dilate(plane, kernel, iterations = 10)
        bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
        diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(plane, bg_img)
        norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img,None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
        result_planes.append(diff_img)
        result_norm_planes.append(norm_img)

    result = cv2.merge(result_planes)
    result_norm = cv2.merge(result_norm_planes)
    return(result_norm)


def process_img(path):
    img = cv2.imread(str(path))
    processed = deshadowVert(img)


    # Adding custom options
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 -l nld+fra+eng --psm 11'


    h, w, c = img.shape
    data = pytesseract.image_to_data(processed,config=custom_config)
    data2 = []
    i = 0
    for b in data.splitlines():
        b = b.split('\t')
        if i == 0:
            i+=1
            next
        else:
            color = 255
            if int(b[10]) > 50:
                data2.append(b[11])
                color=100
            img = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[6]), int(b[7])), (int(b[6])+int(b[8]),int(b[7]) + int(b[9])), (0, color, 0), 2)
    print(data2)
    concati = cv2.hconcat([img,processed])

    cv2.imshow('image',concati)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]
[image]

**---------- EDIT**

Based of @fmw42's comment. I've tried a new function, and called that one (`processed = thresholdingWhite(img)`) instead of `processed = deshadowVert(img)`

The function:

```
def thresholdingWhite(image):
    # Set minimum and max HSV values to display
    sensitivity = 75
    lower = np.array([0,0,255-sensitivity])
    upper = np.array([255,sensitivity,255])

    # Create HSV Image and threshold into a range.
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)
    
    return output
```

Output results have significantly increased with varying the sensitivity. Yet there is still a long way to go for a more fool-proof solution. Suggestions are still welcome to work further on this.

Comment: DNNs should be able to recognize those texts... but I haven't seen anyone actually use them as they should be used. all I see is "text detection" (spits out bounding boxes) and single glyph classification of binarized images, not a DNN that works on grayscale/color images unaltered.

Comment: Try thresholding on white using cv2.inRange().

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: i assume this is too hard for myself to implement / feed to a network?

Comment: @fmw42: very good suggestion. i've altered my opening post with a new function, which greatly improves the results already. More suggestions to improve further are welcome.

Comment: After thresholding, you can use morphology to clean it up to remove small odd regions or better use contours to filter on area.